# How can i Bulk export Media/import files as Excel Sheet (Export only Name of all images)

Tags: magento-1.9, export, media-images

How can i bulk export name of all images presented in the media/import fils in magento root folder?

Note : Is possible export via SSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an SSH session you can `cd` to the directory of interest and type `ls > filenames.txt` to get a list of all filenames in that directory in a text file